# Layover at Charles-de-Gaulle airport in March-April 2021

Tags: paris

I am an Indian citizen living in Geneva as a student with B-permit. I will be going back home for a month. I have a layover at Charles-de-Gaulle airport in Paris for around 16 hours. Am I allowed to leave the airport and visit the city, apart from the curfew hours? I will be having a valid PCR test.

Comment: I am assuming you're contemplating a layover in the coming weeks. Rules during the summer might be different.

Answer (score 7):

You should be OK as far as visa requirements and Covid-related restrictions on entering France are concerned but the Paris region is currently under a lockdown of sorts. Rules are a bit in flux but basically you are not supposed to move around without a good reason (look at the English-language version of the form under [*Attestation de déplacement dérogatoire dans les départements soumis à des "mesures renforcées" entre 6h et 19h*](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestations-de-deplacement)).

Going somewhere less than 10 km away from your home for “physical exercise and walking” is allowed but clearly people are not supposed to go sightseeing. Even if enforcement seems lax, you would also have trouble proving you are less than 10 km away from home so I would conclude that leaving the airport is not allowed at the moment. That would even be the case for French citizens transiting from a less restricted area like Bordeaux or Toulouse.

Answer (score 2):

Even with that long of a layover it is not a good idea. Anything could happen once you leave the airport and I just think it is too risky. For example what happens if you left the airport and lost your passport, you would be stuck in Paris. Not trying to sound like a pessimist just need to be realistic that things do happen. Especially everything happening with COVID, rules and quarantine restrictions are constantly changing, so you are best to just stay at the airport.